# Important Metric Types to monitor GCP PaaS Services apart fro default one's

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-dataproc, stackdriver

Please suggest important built-in metric types for monitoring GKE,GCS,Big Query,Data flow & Data proc  through charts & alerting policies .
By default GCP creates charts for  CPU & Memory utilization and other resource specific charts through default dashboard , Hence apart from those metrics any other important metric which we utilize it .

Example :  Kube_pod_status_phase & kube_node_status_condition metric types for Kubernetes container resource .

These are Prometheus metrics but it is not available in GKE native built-in metrics list but it is available under anthos , which I can't use it for native GKE.

Thanks,
Deena

Comment: This is opinion based question. The "important" metrics would vary depending on your business needs. The question here is what do you want to monitor? What is important for your project? Also, please reed the [How to Ask section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ok , I'll edit the question